# Create $Q Deferred Dynamically for Multiple Db Calls

Tags: angularjs, promise, q, deferred

This is a simplified example, but let's say I have an array of numbers, and I need to make a database call for each item in that array for some reason. The length of the array varies. I make the call in a for loop, where I just pass the id to the call.

I need to wait until ALL the calls return. How do I go about accomplishing this?

My thoughts: The calls themselves are promises, so ideally, I would just make a $q.all for those call promises, but I don't assign any of those calls a variable, so I essentially can't put them in a $q all. I was thinking of generating a new deferred object for all those promises, but I can't figure out the details of how exactly to accomplish this, since I need to identify each call by a number or something.

I don't expect a comprehensive answer by any means, just a general approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// you have an array of numbers
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// let's create an array of promises: each number has its 
// corresponding promise, created by calling the DB with that number
var promises = array.map(function(number) {
    return callDb(number);
});
// so now you have an array of promises

$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // so now, you have an array of promise results
});
```

Comment: That's what I needed, i was over-complicating it badly, thank you very much.

Comment: And if `callDb` genuinely takes a single (Number) argument then, `var promises = array.map(callDb);`.